# How does this recursive function keep track of how many times it has been executed?

Tags: python, recursion

Project Euler problem 14 give the following problem:

> The following iterative sequence is defined for the set of positive integers:
>
> n → n/2 (n is even)
>   n → 3n + 1 (n is odd)
>
> Using the rule above and starting with 13, we generate the following sequence:
>
> 13 → 40 → 20 → 10 → 5 → 16 → 8 → 4 → 2 → 1
>
> It can be seen that this sequence (starting at 13 and finishing at 1) contains 10 terms. Although it has not been proved yet (Collatz Problem), it is thought that all starting numbers finish at 1.
>
> Which starting number, under one million, produces the longest chain?

I found this recursive function which calculates the length of the Collatz chain of a given number. The mathematical logic is very simple and easy to follow. However, I don't understand how the function keeps track of the length of the chain.

The code is as follows:

```py
def find_collatz_chain_length(x):
    if x == 1:
        print('here')
        return 1
    if x % 2 == 0:
        y = x // 2
        print(y)
    else:
        y = x * 3 + 1
        print(y)
    return find_collatz_chain_length(y) + 1
```

I have added the print statements to follow the logic when executed. For example:

```py
print(find_collatz_chain_length(13))
```

Then I get the following output:

```
40 
20
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
here
10
```

Which makes sense (to me) up until its returns the length of the chain (10). I know it is to do with the `+1` in the final return statement as altering this results in the wrong length. If anyone could explain to me how the function is keeping track of the length without a list or counter then that would be great.

Comment: Think about that `return` statement. What are you adding `1` to?

Comment: It's asking the function to return the next value of the collatz chain. I feel like the answer is staring me in the face but I'm having a brain freeze.

Comment: What will _that_ function call return?

Answer (score 1):

Let's replace the function call with its return value. We start with

```
find_collatz_chain_length(13)
```

That will return

```
find_collatz_chain_length(40) + 1
```

Looking at the function call, it will return `find_collatz_chain_length(20) + 1`, but we already have a `+ 1` from the first time the function was called:

```
(find_collatz_chain_length(20) + 1) + 1
```

*That* function call returns `find_collatz_chain_length(10) + 1`:

```
(((find_collatz_chain_length(10) + 1) + 1) + 1)
```

Each time the function gets called it adds a `+ 1`, until the input to the function is `1` at which point it stops calling itself and just returns 1. You end up with something like

```
(((((1) + 1) + 1) + 1) ... + 1)
```

with one `1` for each time the function was called. Add them up, and you get your chain length.